# Access GAID in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-advertising-id

Is it possible to retrieve GAID in a Django server?

Here is my scenario:
I want to create a unique link in my Django project and send it to a user (it's a referral link). When the user click the link it will redirect to my server so then I can log its click and then user will redirect to an app store to download my app.
Is it possible for me to get its GAID before installing the app, right after clicking the link?

If yes so, then how? I searched already couldn't find anything helpful. I appreciate if anyone can offer me a documentation or something like that.